# Регулярные выражения js,адрес

Tags: javascript

109280, Москва, ул.Восточная, 51, кв.4

индекс и адрес

В две группы, но в адресс без Москва, подскажите, как регуляркой это сделать? вообще идей нет

Comment: Разделить через запятую?

Comment: да, разделить...

Answer (score 2):

Работать будет толькопри условии, что данные разделены через `,` .

```js
var s = '109280, Москва, ул.Восточная, 51, кв.4'.split(', ')
console.log(s[0], s[2]);
```